# possible query shortening for pivot-like SELECT statement, using case

Tags: mysql

i have a 'formaction' table (id,inputtime,username,action) which purpose is to record all users action (simply sign-in, sign-out time for now). I created the following query to know how many times the employee sign-in to the program, which output is exactly what i expected.

But, my employer have at least few dozens employee accessing the program. typing it one by one just like what i did is not gonna be an easy task. Is it possible to do join with 'master employee' table (id,username,password)

Thank u

```
SELECT a.date,SUM(a.name1) name1, SUM(a.name2) name2,SUM(a.name3) name3,SUM(a.name4) name4,
       SUM(a.name5) name5,SUM(a.name6) name6,SUM(a.name7) name7, SUM(a.name8) name8, SUM(a.name9) name9
FROM (
  SELECT 
    date(f.inputtime) date,
    case when users = "name1" then 1 end AS name1,
    case when users = "name2" then 1 end AS name2,
    case when users = "name3" then 1 end AS name3,
    case when users = "name4" then 1 end AS name4,
    case when users = "name5" then 1 end AS name5,
    case when users = "name6" then 1 end AS name6,
    case when users = "name7" then 1 end AS name7,
    case when users = "name8" then 1 end AS name8,
    case when users = "name9" then 1 end AS name9
  FROM formaction f WHERE ACTION = 'sign in'  ORDER BY date(inputtime) DESC)a  
GROUP BY  a.date
```

which output something like this (kinda like pivot):

```
date  |name1|name2|name3|name4|name5|name6|name7|name8|name9
1dec13|  1  |  2  |  1  |  7  |  3  |null |  1  |null |  2  |
2dec13|  1  |  3  |  1  |  5  |  1  |  1  |null |  3  |  1  |
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all a streamlined version of your query might look like

```
SELECT DATE(inputtime) date, 
       SUM(username = 'user1') `user1`,
       SUM(username = 'user2') `user2`,
       ... 
  FROM formaction 
 WHERE action = 'sign in' 
 GROUP BY DATE(inputtime)
```

Now, to be able to dynamically bring usernames from `employee` table you can use dynamic SQL

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('SUM(username = ''', username, ''') `', username, '`'))
  INTO @sql
  FROM employee;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT DATE(inputtime) date, ', @sql,
                  '  FROM formaction
                    WHERE action = ''sign in''
                    GROUP BY DATE(inputtime)');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/538f1/1)** demo

---

To simplify things on the calling end you can wrap it into a stored procedure

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE report()
BEGIN
  SET @sql = NULL;

  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('SUM(username = ''', username, ''') `', username, '`'))
    INTO @sql
    FROM employee;

  SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT DATE(inputtime) date, ', @sql,
                    '  FROM formaction
                      WHERE action = ''sign in''
                      GROUP BY DATE(inputtime)');

  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And then use it

```
CALL report();
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ad8d6/1)** demo

Comment: Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?

Comment: sorry took a longggg time to reply. It works! and it's awesome! I managed to auto-calculate salaries for all employee in the company every month. export the data for auto payroll by the bank. simplify HR job a lot. no matter how much people come and go, the code handle it perfectly. Thanks man :)